# Matrix of permutations?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, permutation

so i have a matrix struct and i have to fill with permutations ranging from 0~nr_vals in N columns. I finished the permutation part but i cannot figure out the pointers with the array. Any Help would be appreciated. There is a printing function that i call and all i does it prints and thats it.
Its supposed to print the permutations(DONE) after allocating them to the matrix. what am i doing wrong and also how do i free the matrix?

printing function:

```
void print_2D(matrix_ptr mat);

struct matrix_2D_struct {
    int** data_arr;
    int rows;
    int cols;
};
typedef struct matrix_2D_struct * matrix_ptr;

matrix_ptr perm_rec_2(int N, int nr_vals) {
    struct matrix_2D_struct *matrix = malloc(sizeof *matrix);
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    prem_rec_helpTwoForMatrix (N, nr_vals, i, matrix->data_arr, j);
    return NULL;
}

void prem_rec_helpTwoForMatrix(int N, int nr_vals, int i, int **a[], int j)
{
    i = N - 1;
    while(a[i][j] < nr_vals){
        a[i][j]++;
    }
    while(i >= 0 && a[i][j] == nr_vals){
        i--;
    }
    if(i < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    a[i][j]++;
    while(++i < N)
    {
        a[i] = 0;
    }
    prem_rec_helpTwoForMatrix(N, nr_vals, i, **a, j);
}
```

Comment: Where do you allocate `data_arr`?

Comment: When looking the source code, the variable `j` does'nt change and stays to 0. One error at the last while why `a[i] = 0;` instead of `a[i][j]` ?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani where would i allocate?

Comment: @J.Piquard a writing error. fixed that line but does not change anything.

Comment: @Abeer another error which can go up to the Stackover Exception is certainly due to the set of `i = N - 1;` instead of using the argument `int i` on the call of `prem_rec_helpTwoForMatrix()` ==> i never change at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer:

After allocating `matrix`, you have to allocate `matrix->data_arr`.

Assuming that the array is `N`x`N` large:

```
struct matrix_2D_struct *matrix = malloc(sizeof *matrix);

if (N < 1)
{
    printf("error!\n");
    return ...
}

matrix->data_arr = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    matrix->data_arr[i] = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
```

Initialization (as suggested in comment)

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        matrix->data_arr[i][j] = 0;
```

Now you can test to see if it works:

```
matrix->data_arr[2][0] = 20;
matrix->data_arr[0][4] = 4;
printf("%d\n", matrix->data_arr[2][0]);
printf("%d\n", matrix->data_arr[0][4]);
```

When you no longer need the data, you can free it (the data is freed automatically when you exit the program)

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    free(matrix->data_arr[i]);
free(matrix->data_arr);
free(matrix);
```

Comment: @Abeer, after allocating the 2d array, you have to initialized all cells with 0 before the first `while(a[i][j] < nr_vals)`.

Comment: `matrix_ptr perm_rec_2(int N, int nr_vals) {
    struct matrix_2D_struct *matrix = malloc(sizeof *matrix);
    if (N < 1)
    {
        printf("error!\n");
        return matrix;}
    int multi = N-1;
    multi = multi*multi;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < multi; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
            matrix->data_arr[i][j] = malloc(multi*sizeof(int));}
    }
    for (i = 0; i < multi; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
            matrix->data_arr[i][j] = 0;}
    }
    prem_rec_helpTwoForMatrix (N, nr_vals, 0, matrix->data_arr, 0);
    return NULL;
}
`

Comment: what the heck is that?